# Pascal compiler running on the server

Tags: apache, compiler-construction, pascal

do you have any ideas, how to compile pascal file (*.pas) on the server? Thank you.

Comment: Needs more information. For a start, what kind of server are we talking about here? A web server? File server? Database server? Automated-build box?

Answer (score 1):

You don't name server type, but Free pascal ( http://www.freepascal.org ) comes with nearly every Linux distribution nowadays, as well in the FreeBSD ports and on Mac OS X (x86+ppc + 64-bit of both, via fink or standalone .dmg installer).

For windows and dos there are normal  all-in-one installers at http://www.freepascal.org

If you want more Delphi like RAD editing, you probably want Lazarus ( http://Lazarus.freepascal.org , also available for the above platforms, except for dos)

Solaris x86+sparc exist, but are a bit experimental.

If it is a windows server, Delphi is also possible, but free versions are hard to get (if at all) nowadays.

Comment: I support using of Free Pascal Compiler. On Windows one can also try PascalABC.NET (http://pascalabc.net/). This project even have their own web development environment under construction (http://pascalabc.net/WDE/).

Answer (score 0):

Pascal is pretty uncommon these days. Unless there's a reason for the server to have it, it won't. The apache tag here seems to indicate you mean a webserver. Webservers generally don't have Pascal compilers.

The GNU Pascal Compiler is called `gpc`. It's built upon GCC, the popular C compiler, up to version 3.4. See http://www.gnu-pascal.de . Maybe you can manage to install it, if the server has an old copy of GCC up for compatibility's sake.

Comment: GNU Pascal hasn't had a release in a long time. Unless the architecture is not supported by Free Pascal, I wouldn't bother.